# How to play video in-app using the YouTube API?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, load, youtube-api

I have my `GDataEntryBase` from the `GDataFeedYouTubeVideo` and now I need to load the youtube video for watching.

I have searched the web and can't work it out, there is very little documented on this using the YouTube API. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use this below to include youtube videos in your app or maybe emmbed.

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/hcyoutubeparser

Answer (score -1):

You can play it using HTML5 webview. It will play the YouTube video. But it create problem for 4.* devices. Thanks
Santanu